# How to count the string of letters in kmer

Tags: r, count

im trying to calculate population proportion 5-mers in the 100,000 nucleotides , 5-mers of AATAA. How many AATAA repeated in the data.

```
dog_ch38 <- read.GenBank("NC_006620.3")
dog_ch38 <- dog_ch38$NC_006620.3[1:100000]
dog_ch38 <- c2s(ape::as.character.DNAbin(dog_ch38))
dog_ch38 <- str_to_upper(dog_ch38)
 kmer_to_index <- function(kmer){
+     n  <- str_length(kmer)
+     letter_value  <- c("A" = 0, "C" = 1, "G" = 2, "T" = 3)
+     base  <- 1
+     index  <- 1
+     for( i in n:1){
+         nucleotide <- str_sub(kmer,start = i,end = i)
+         index  <- index + base * letter_value[nucleotide]
+         base  <- base * 4
+     }
+     return(as.numeric(index))
+ }
k <- 5
kmers <- numeric(4^k)
kmers
N <- str_length(dog_ch38)
> for (i in 1:(N - k + 1)) {
+   kmer <- str_sub(dog_ch38, i, i + k - 1)
+   index <- kmer_to_index(kmer)
+   kmers[index] <- kmers[index] + 1
+ }
```

but getting error like this:

```
Error in kmers[index] <- kmers[index] + 1 : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In 1:(N - k + 1) :
  numerical expression has 100000 elements: only the first used
2: In n:1 : numerical expression has 100000 elements: only the first used

seqinr::count(dog_ch38[1,], 5)
Error in dog_ch38[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

what i actually expecting to see as a result is:

```
## aaaaa accaa taaag aataa
##   75   75     47    92
```

I'm definitely new to this function and if anyone can guide me how to solve it and some examples to look at. Thank you!

Comment: Check if you are getting any NA in the `index <- kmer_to_index(kmer)` by having a `print(index)` after the statement.  If it is an NA, then use either `tryCatch` to by pass that or create an `if/else` condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `oligonucleotideFrequency()` function from the `Biostrings` package can help. Here's an example with artificial data.

```
  library(Biostrings) # requires appropriate Bioconductor install
  s1 <- sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), 10^5, TRUE)
  s1 <- DNAString(paste(s1, collapse = ""))
  kmers <- oligonucleotideFrequency(s1, width = 5)
```

The function has returned a named numeric vector of all **possible** kmers. You can use this feature to extract your kmer of interest. There should be about 100 in this example.

```
  kmers["AATAA"] # actual count varies because of random sampling
> AATAA 
>  102
```

Check out the help page for this function. With the default arguments, it will return **overlapping** kmers. This can be controlled with the `step` option as illustrated in this example:

```
  s2 <- DNAString("AATAATAATAA")
  kmers1 <- oligonucleotideFrequency(s2, width = 5)
  kmers2 <- oligonucleotideFrequency(s2, width = 5, step = 5)

# See all the 5-mers found with step = 1 (default) versus step = 5
  kmers1[kmers1 != 0]
> AATAA ATAAT TAATA 
>     3     2     2 
  kmers2[kmers2 != 0]
> AATAA TAATA 
>     1     1
```

### EDIT

I found (still find) the variety of formats for handling DNA sequences confusing and it appears that there is a need to convert the compact binary form returned by `read.GenBank()` to the character representation in `Biostrings`. They both are remarkably efficient.

The conversion can be done on the list of binary objects that `read.GenBank()` returns or you can use the `as.character = TRUE` option to have raw characters returned. I show the latter approach here.

```
# Using package ape to read GenBank file, Biostrings for analysis
  library(ape)
  library(Biostrings)

# By default, read.GenBank returns a list of DNA sequences in compact binary form.
# This asks it to return a list of character vectors. 
  dog_ch38 <- read.GenBank("NC_006620.3", as.character = TRUE)
  str(dog_ch38)
> List of 1
>  $ NC_006620.3: chr [1:23914537] "n" "n" "n" "n" ...
>  - attr(*, "species")= chr "Canis_lupus_familiaris"

# Now convert the first (and only) member of the list to a single character string
  txt <- paste(dog_ch38[[1]], collapse = "")
  print(nchar(txt))
> [1] 23914537

# And now convert the character string to a DNAString
  s <- DNAString(txt)

# This is the form that can be handed to oligonucleotideFrequency
  km <- oligonucleotideFrequency(s[1:10^5], 5)
  km["AATAA"]
> AATAA 
>   176
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i have seen similar example, but i couldn't understand where at that point i should place my data (dog_ch38), since i have to count kmer[AATAA] in that data.

Comment: You're welcome. I take your comment to mean there's still some uncertainty about how to get the data into a useable form. Hopefully the edit I added helps. Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

Vadim is right! Minor update: you don't need this code chunk:

```
# Now convert the first (and only) member of the list to a single character string
  txt <- paste(dog_ch38[[1]], collapse = "")
```

for your code because you have already used the c2s() and str_to_upper() functions. Here is a simple method that works:

```
#load libraries
library(ape)
library(tidyverse)
library(Biostrings) # installed by 1) install.packages("BiocManager") and 2) BiocManager::install("Biostrings")

dog_ch38 <- read.GenBank("NC_006620.3")

#first 100k nucleotides
dog_ch38_sub <- dog_ch38$NC_006620.3[1:100000] # the subset
print(nchar(dog_ch38_sub) # verify you have 100k

#convert to a form that Biostrings understands
dog_ch38_sub <- c2s(ape::as.character.DNAbin(dog_ch38_sub))
dog_ch38_sub <- str_to_upper(dog_ch38_sub)
dog_ch38_sub <- DNAString(dog_ch38_sub)

km <- oligonucleotideFrequency(dog_ch38_sub[1:100000], 5)
count_AATAA <- km["AATAA"]

#your proportion
count_AATAA / nchar(dog_ch38_sub)
```

Thank you.